# Why do I have no display on a newly built computer.

Tags: motherboard, troubleshooting

I built a computer (parts list below). The first time I started it up all the lights come on. My RAM, which is an LED type, lights up. My Fans start spinning, including the ones on my graphics card. My key board works (mouse lights up, and keyboard will let me do Caps lock i.e. lights up as well.

My problem is that even with everything lighting up.. Neither the integrated HDMI port nor the graphics card send anything to the monitor..? Ideas for why that might be? Things to try?

Nothing has been uploaded to the computer yet.. No windows or Linux nor any drivers.

(Parts)
DEEPCOOL GAMMAXX 400 CPU Cooler 4 Heatpipes 120mm PWM Fan Blue LED INTEL/AMD AM4 Compatible

Corsair Vengeance RGB 16GB (2x8GB) DDR4 2666

TP-Link Wireless Dual Band PCI Express Adapter

Samsung 850 EVO 250GB 2.5-Inch SATA III Internal SSD

GIGABYTE GA-AB350-Gaming AMD RYZEN AM4 B350  DDR4 Motherboard

AMD Ryzen 5 1600X Processor

Microsoft Windows 10 Home USB Flash Drive

Seagate 2TB BarraCuda SATA 6Gb/s 64MB Cache 3.5-Inch Internal Hard Drive

EVGA SuperNOVA 650 G1, 80+ GOLD 650W, Fully Modular

NZXT S340 Compact ATX Mid-Tower Case

Gigabyte Graphics Cards GV-N75TWF2OC-4GI

Comment: Do you get any beeps or error flashes that your motherboard manual has a table of that might give a clue as to if something's not working to allow POST?

Comment: Have you tried DisplayPort?

Comment: Make sure your display cable is connected to graphic card output.

Answer (score 0):

Usually a dedicated graphic cards takes over from your computer's default graphic port, but initially it's driver is not installed and that's why you can get no signal.

I would suggest that you remove the graphic card and start your computer with the screen connected to the graphic port.

Then install the graphic card driver and restart your computer afterwards.
Your graphic card should work.

When installing the graphic card driver, it may happen that the software seeks a graphic card that is absent from your computer. For this reason, you may have to hot plug the graphic card after the computer was started, but after the signal was detected on the native graphic port.
I feel this trick a bit unsafe, so use it as a last resort.